# Allow SharePoint site owner to extend guest expiration (SPO)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I understand that by default, only site collection/SharePoint admins can extend guest expiration. But this isn't practical for my purposes. I want site owners to also be able to do this. If there is a way to customize it so some site owners can and some can't, even better. Is either possible?

Comment: Do you mean "site admin"? If yes, see this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/manage-guest-expiration-for-a-site-25bee24f-42ad-4ee8-8402-4186eed74dea).

Comment: If site owner can also be called site admin, then sure that's what I mean. But I'm an owner and don't have access to manage guest expiration. Your link doesn't help...

Comment: If you have not been given this permission, you'll have to ask for it.

Comment: Got it. I will try to be clearer. Since I'm also in training to be a SharePoint IT admin in general, I'm curious what configuration has to be done in the back-end to grant the permission? I've checked my training resources and haven't found it, so curious. (External sharing is already enabled for the site.)